# Keep HDRI visible in viewport while "Transparent" is checked in film

Tags: hdri

Is it possible to keep the HDRI visible in the viewport while "Transparent" is turned on under "Film" in the Render options?

I would like to see the background but not have to uncheck this every time between renders.

Comment: You could always right-click on the Transparent checkbox and add it to the quick menu. Then it's instantly available by pressing 'Q'  without having to go back to the settings properties every time.

Comment: I do love my quick menu, hate having to add more to it. Thank you for the idea, a good bandaid for the time being!